# How to UnitTest static void functions in android (java)

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

I have a class `FileCreator.class` and it has only static methods inside it. I want to test the function void `createTempFile(String path)`. And i understand that having void functions is bad practice because they only create side effects. But i need to test this functions side effect (if it created the file). I tried using

```
Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(FileCreator.class).createTempFile(ArgumentMatchers.any(String.class)))
```

but it does not recognize createTempFile() as a function. I can easy fix this by making the method return boolean if it created the file but this will work only in this case and i was looking for a more general solution.

Comment: Why are you not directly calling method createTempFile from your tests?

Comment: 1) You should not mock the method you want to test, 2) static methods do not lend themselves easily to unit testing. Mockito in particular does not mock static methods. You need PowerMock. If the FileCreator class is under your control, it should not be hard to alter the design to something more readily testable.

Comment: `T Stubber.when(T mock)` expects a mock and you provide to the `FileCreator` class instance. It will be helpless as what you need is mocking the instance of the class.   
Besides you try to mock the method of the class under test : `createTempFile()`. It makes no sense.   
Please refine your question and explain the actual behavior of the method under test.

Comment: I assume you don't need mockito to test this class. The main purpose of your test for `createTempFile()` is to check if the file has been created. Test that and nothing else.